# Delete duplicates within a single collection c#

Tags: c#, collections

I'm new to C#, here is my problem

My expected result is removing the entire row of ABC. 
Both rows (with duplicate ABC) will be removed.

I need to do it the iterative way. Can't use distinct and stuff as recommended by the other post.

I tried to remove duplicates but it didn't work.

So i decided to add the non-duplicates to a new collection.

But it isn't working as well.

CollectionIn --> My sample collection

```
| Folder|    Times 
------------------------
| ABC   |      3       |
| CDE   |      2       | 
| ACD   |      2       |
| ABC   |      1       | 


CollectionOut = new DataTable(); 
CollectionOut.Columns.Add("Folder"); 
CollectionOut.Columns.Add("Times");

bool duplicate = false;

for (int i = 0; i < CollectionIn.Rows.Count; i++) 
{
 string value1 = CollectionIn.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString().ToLower(); 

for (int z = 0; z < i; z++) 
{
 string value2 = CollectionIn.Rows[z].ItemArray[0].ToString().ToLower(); 

   if (value1 == value2)
        {
            duplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }

  if (!duplicate)
  {
           CollectionOut.Rows.Add(value1); 
           }
}
```

Can anyone help to take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @Dragonthoughts He explicitely stated, he can't use `.Distinct()` (for whatever reasons)

Comment: Hi. Yes. It has some issues with distinct() and i needed this quick fix before i look into other issues.

Comment: _"I need to do it the iterative way. Can't use distinct "_ Why not?

Comment: @JAYY just to be clear: You desired output should only contain rows for `CDE`and `ACD` but none of `ABC`?

Comment: @derpirscher yes

Comment: The namespace issue comes from missing `using System.Linq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `Linq-To-DataTable`:

```
List<DataRow> duplicates = CollectionIn.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Folder"))
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(grp => grp)
    .ToList();
duplicates.ForEach(CollectionIn.Rows.Remove);
```

This will remove the duplicates from the original collection(DataTable) without creating a new.

Comment: Hi. I added ToList<DataRow>(); since there is an error using just ToList(). But it's still not working. Nothing being removed from CollectionIn.

Comment: @JAYY: I don't know why you got a compiler error without `ToList<DataRow>` because the type could be inferred from the query(`SelectMany` selects multiple DataRows). What framework version are you using? Does the query compile and run now? Is `duplicates` really empty? Use the debugger.

Answer (score 6):

Since you dont want to use Distinct, you cant do it with `LINQ` like:

```
var newList = myList.GroupBy(s=>s).Where(s => s.Count() == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: You select groups of DataRows, not DataRows. OP wants a new DataTable or remove the duplicates from the old. Also, this doesn't find duplicates by `Folder` but by reference, so this will never find any duplicate because a DataTable cannot contain same references of DataRows. The DataTable even throws an exception in that case: _"This row already belongs to this table"_